# How to use software watchpoints in LLDB?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, breakpoint, lldb

After trying to use watch command, LLDB said the device had 0 available hardware watchpoints. In GDB you can use

```
set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0
```

How do you disable hardware watchpoints in LLDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know there are limitations to using watchpoints: there are a finite amount of watchpoints permitted per architecture (typically 4) and the “watched” size of memory usually caps out at 8 bytes. Therefore, it is important to delete them after they are no longer needed.

You can delete a watchpoint in `lldb` using the `watchpoint delete` command and passing the watchpoint ID as an argument.

Example:

```
(lldb) watchpoint delete 1
1 watchpoints deleted.
```

Or we can use,

```
(lldb) w delete 1
1 watchpoints deleted.
```

To delete all watchpoints - simply omit the last argument.

Comment: Oh so lldb does not have support for software watchpoints unlike gdb? Its after a reboot and its only one watchpoint i have added.

Comment: @Silent LLDB doesn't have software watchpoint. Make sure your watchpoint expression size is less or equal to hardware watchpoint size that your machine can handle.

Comment: I guess this is a definite answer. Thanks